# Watson, types of condidions

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I have one example.
I create some intent inside Watson Conversation, and I want to knows how I can do some condition for it?

**Example:**

**Watson:** Hi, tell me your number

**Me:** 99999-9999 (and have some regex inside advanced conversation flows, i check wih context variables in the case is number and works fine)

The conversation will only continue if he enters the 9 numbers correctly.

I try it:

[check image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVv5b.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression to parse the input and extract the number using syntax similar to

then have a dialog node condition based on the number extracted.

Comment: What does your regex and condition look like?

Comment: in the case is 11 numbers and the regex is: "number": `"<?input.text.extract('^[^\\d]*[\\d]{11}[^\\d]*$',0)?>"`

Comment: You will need two conversation nodes. In the first the regex will get you the number. there should be no response, instead the flow should go into a second node which checks the number.

Comment: I want to knows how to verify... you can post some example?